# How to block bootstrap in R?

Tags: r, block, robustness

I'm trying to run a block bootstrapping function on some time series data (monthly interest rates for ~15 years).

My data is in a csv file with no header, all comprising one column and going down by row.

I installed the package **bootstrap** because **tsboot** wouldn't work for me.

Here is my code:

```
testFile = read.csv("\\Users\\unori/sample_data.csv")
theta <- function(x){mean(x)} 
results = bootstrap(testFile,100,theta)
```

It tells me there are at least 50 errors. All of them say "In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"

What to do? It runs when I use the example in the documentation. I think it must be how my data is stored/imported?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Iain, the problems lies in this. You are providing a data frame, and some of your columns are not numbers, they might be factors or characters. Hence when you do mean on them, it gives you this error

Comment: You are almost there. Can you do dput(head(testFile,10)) and paste the output as part of your post? Also elaborate on which column do you want to calculate the mean on? Thanks!

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. I did the dput(head(testFIle, 10)) and the output is: 
structure(list(X20 = c(2L, 4L, 5L, 16L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 12L, 4L, 
12L)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame").

When I simply input 'testFile' it returns the entire column of numbers though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to supply a working, minimal example that reproduces your problem! Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see how to make a minimal reproducible example.

The error messages tells you that the thing you want to calculate the mean of, is not a number! So R will just return NA.

Suggestions for debugging:

1. Does the object 'testFile' exist?
2. What is the output of

   str(testFile)

This works for me:

```
library(bootstrap)

testFile <- cars[,1]

theta <- function(x){mean(x)} 
results = bootstrap(testFile,100,theta)
```

Comment: Thank you for that. Your example also works for me. I decided to be lazy and just copy+paste the excel values into R itself and it works.

One more question: this package also allows for **block bootstrapping**, seen as 

```bootstrap(x, nb = 1, statistic = NULL, b = NULL,
          type = c("stationary","block"), ...)```

But when I try to use type block, it won't compile.

Comment: Please supply a minima reproducible example of your problem. Otherwise I won't be able to help you further. Also, consider accepting the answer if it solved your initial question.